# How to do a case-insensitive search for non-English characters in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sqlite, internationalization

Right now I use this piece of code to find items:

```
where("lower(name) like ?", "%#{search_word.downcase}%")
```

But it doesn't work correctly with Russian characters.

So I tried this:

```
where("lower(name) like ?", "%#{search_word.mb_chars.downcase.to_s}%")
```

but it didn't work either.

What do I do?

Update: Okay. If I write `ilike` instead of `like` it seems to work with Postgres. How do I make it work with sqlLite too? =)

Comment: I wonder if JRuby handles it any better?  It may use the Java functionality, and Java has some excellent internationalization.

Comment: @KeithBennett sooo cooool. I will have to install jruby and jdk just because 1 line of code?=)

Comment: I realize that this would probably not be important enough for you to switch, but if you did have JRuby, it would be interesting to see if it worked any better.  I use rvm, and have JRuby installed -- if you have a script that would test it (including SQLite setup) I would be happy to run it and report the results.

Comment: Come to think of it, since it would just be a test of `downcase`, it wouldn't even need any SQLite code.  You could just give me 2 strings which should be equal when `downcase` is called on both of them.

Comment: I have had  similar problem and have a comment in my code: for sqlite LOWER work only with ASCII characters - maybe it's show direction for your search.

Comment: @KeithBennett specially for you: `string1 = Привет` `string2 = привет`

Comment: @user2950593 Thanks for that!  I tested it and found that JRuby's downcase also failed to convert the string correctly, but Java, called from JRuby *did* process it correctly (see https://gist.github.com/keithrbennett/48295f6fd9ddcdf12a165218e7d900ad).  Not that that helps us though. ;)

Comment: @user2950593 please provide your postgres config you initialized you db with

Comment: @retgoat I am just deploying to heroku and I have gem  `gem 'pg', '0.15.1'` in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sawa over at the [Easy way to convert numbers into ordinals in words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274238/easy-way-to-convert-numbers-into-ordinals-in-words) issue, I just found out about the amazing `twitter_cldr` gem.  Check this out:

```
2.3.0 :001 > require 'twitter_cldr'
 => true
2.3.0 :002 > 'Привет'.localize.casefold.to_s
 => "привет"
2.3.0 :005 > 'Привет'.localize.casefold.to_s == 'привет'.localize.casefold.to_s
 => true
```

So just use this gem to get the lower case string to compare with the data base value.