# Easy way to convert numbers into ordinals in words

Tags: ruby

Any easy way to convert `1` into `"first"` and `2` into `"second"`, etc? Even if it's a library or a gem, any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite is to use the `twitter_cldr` gem.

```
require "twitter_cldr"
1.localize(:en).to_rbnf_s("SpelloutRules", "spellout-ordinal") # => "first"
2.localize(:en).to_rbnf_s("SpelloutRules", "spellout-ordinal") # => "second"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm only aware of active_support's ordinalize.  The following example produces 1st, 2nd, 3rd, which isn't exactly as the question asked.

```
1.ordinalize # returns "1st"
2.ordinalize # returns "2nd"
```